# Array Index Confusion

Tags: c

Can someone explain to me how it displays the value of x[2]?
When the array index is x[4].

```
Array x 
{
x[0] x[1] x[2] x[3] x[4] x[5] x[6] x[7]
16.0 12.0 6.0 8.0 2.5 12.0 14.0 –54.5
printf("%.1f", x[(int)x[4]]); Displays 6.0 (value of x[2])
}
```

Comment: If you want to show us code, then please show us *valid* code. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: `x[4]` is `2.5`.  `(int)x[4]` is `2`.  `x[(int)x[4]]` means `x[2]` which is `6.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x[4] has a value 2.5, when prefixed with "(int)" what happens is that you "cast" the resulting value into an integer thereby dropping the decimal part without doing any rounding-off to it. This is called "Type casting" or converting from one data type to another. In this case, the value of x[4] which is in "float" is converted into an integer.

The equation will become:
x[ (int)x[4] ] = x[ 2 ] = 6.0

Comment: @whitelotus Its best to say thanks by accepting my answer. Cheers!